# Azure Web service Manage your accout link giving error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

So this is my first web application that I have launched user Azure, so I am a little new to this. 
I finally managed to get the AD authentication working properly, but now once a user is logged in they can not  access the "Manage your account" tab that are automatically created for you when you produce a asp.net web app generally found in the /accounts/* directory.

When the user clicks on their AD name that directs them to the /Accounts/Manage page they will get this error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a 
connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to 
allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

This process works perfectly fine when I run the app locally on my machine but not when its using the AD account information.

My question is why is it doing this? and where can I fix it?

Comment: Check your database connection strings.

Comment: That was my first thought, but i could not find a connection string found in the /Accounts/*  directory.

Answer (score 0):

I tested Azure AD using the steps provided in following article.

[Developing ASP.NET Apps with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory)

The project template didn't create the default /Accounts/Manage page for me. I am using Visual Studio 2017.

> That was my first thought, but i could not find a connection string found in the /Accounts/* directory.

Please also check the web.config in the root directory. Is there a connection string configuration section like following. Please note that the local database is not work with Azure Web App, you could store the account information in [Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/).

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: I suggest you remote debug your web application to find out  which line of code will cause the exception.